# Depositing Weth ERC20 from Brownie into Aave Pool in contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, brownie, aave

I am tying to do a simple deposit into an Aave V2 pool with Python Brownie and Solidity on a mainnet-fork but my transaction keeps getting reverted and I dont know why.

In brownie, I call my function `send_to_aave()` to deploy my main contract, which I pass in a Weth address and Aave Pool registry address.

Then, I approve the aave pool, weth erc20 address, my address and an amount all with brownie functions.

After that, I call my solidity function `transferToAave()` with brownie to `deposit()` the funds into an Aave pool.

A majority of this code I grabbed from Patrick Collins Aave tutorial, so I know the Brownie code will deposit if I uncomment out this line in my `transfer_to_aave()` function : `# aave_pool.deposit(erc20_address, amount, account.address, 0, {"from": account})`

I've read the aave docs and made a bunch of different changes in my solidity contract, but i cant figure out what the issue is.

The only problem I've been able to detect is that the Weth ERC20 address that gets approved in Brownie `0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2` is a different checksum inside the solidity contract `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`. The Erc20 address becomes tokenUsedForPayment inside the solidity contract.
I pasted my event log output below.

### Error

```
Transaction sent: 0x9158e07b307a9c77974bec4e7182ad7aae24e8f18d80b09de60ac22c637dcd55
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 5
  LandLord.transferToAave confirmed (SafeERC20: low-level call failed)   Block: 14774532   Gas used: 173499 (1.45%)

  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 272, in main
    send_to_aave()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 250, in send_to_aave
    transfer_to_aave(
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 219, in transfer_to_aave
    tx = land_contract.transferToAave(amount, {"from": account})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1710, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1583, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 682, in transfer
    receipt._raise_if_reverted(exc)
  File "brownie/network/transaction.py", line 446, in _raise_if_reverted
    raise exc._with_attr(
VirtualMachineError: revert: SafeERC20: low-level call failed
Trace step -1, program counter 263:
  File "contracts/LandLord.sol", line 63, in LandLord.transferToAave:    
        // Deposit the _amount in the LendingPool

        //emit seeme(address(aavePool), _amount, address(msg.sender), address(tokenUsedForPayments));
        aavePool.deposit(address(tokenUsedForPayments), _amount, address(msg.sender), 0);
        //tokenUsedForPayments.approve(address(aavePool), rent);
        //lendingService.depositFunds(rent);
    }
Terminating local RPC client...
```

### Brownie code

```
def get_lending_pool():
    lending_pool_addresses_provider = interface.ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["lending_pool_addresses_provider"]
    )
    lending_pool_address = lending_pool_addresses_provider.getLendingPool()
    lending_pool = interface.ILendingPool(lending_pool_address)
    return lending_pool, lending_pool_address


def approve_erc20(amount, spender, erc20_address, account):
    print("Approving ERC20 token...")
    erc20 = interface.IERC20(erc20_address)
    tx = erc20.approve(spender, amount, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Approved!")
    return tx


def transfer_to_aave(amount, erc20_address, aave_pool, account):
    
    land_contract = LandLord[-1]

    print(f"AAVVEE ADDRESS: {aave_pool.address}!!!\n")
    print(f"ERC20 ADDRESS: {erc20_address}!!!\n")
    print(f"Aacount ADDRESS: {account.address}!!!\n")

    approve_erc20(amount, aave_pool.address, erc20_address, account)

    # aave_pool.deposit(erc20_address, amount, account.address, 0, {"from": account})
    tx = land_contract.transferToAave(amount, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print(tx.events)
    print("Deposited!")


def send_to_aave():

    # set amount
    amount = Web3.toWei(0.001, "ether")

    # get account
    account = get_account()

    # get weth token
    erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]

    # fund account
    if network.show_active() in ["mainnet-fork"]:
        get_weth(account=account)

    # get pool and address
    aave_pool, lending_pool_address = get_lending_pool()
    
    # deploy contract and pass in lending_pool regsitry address
    LandLord.deploy(
        erc20_address,
        lending_pool_address,
        {"from": account},
    )

    # call to deposit into aave
    transfer_to_aave(
        amount=amount,
        erc20_address=erc20_address,
        aave_pool=aave_pool,
        account=account,
    )
```

### Solidity Code

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.8.0;

import { IERC20 } from "../interfaces/IERC20.sol";

import { ILendingPool } from "../interfaces/ILendingPool.sol";

contract LandLord {

    IERC20 public tokenUsedForPayments;
    ILendingPool public aavePool;

    event printme(address aavePool, uint256 _amount, address sender, address tokenUsedForPayments);

    constructor (
        address _tokenUsedToPay,
        address _lendingService /*uint updateInterval*/
    ) public {
        tokenUsedForPayments = IERC20(_tokenUsedToPay);
        aavePool = ILendingPool(_lendingService);
    }

    function transferToAave(uint256 _amount) public {
        // require(tokenUsedForPayments.allowance(tenant, address(this)) >= rent, "No Allowance");
        //tokenUsedForPayments.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(aavePool), _amount);
        
        //tokenUsedForPayments.approve(address(aavePool), _amount);
        // Deposit the _amount in the LendingPool

        aavePool.deposit(address(tokenUsedForPayments), _amount, address(msg.sender), 0);

        emit printme(address(aavePool), _amount, address(msg.sender), address(tokenUsedForPayments));

    }
```

### Output of function transferToAave() when I comment out aave.deposit() to emit event

```
Launching 'ganache-cli --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --fork.url https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/762bffe1e537416580c803e6ae57d3f7 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.mnemonic brownie --server.port 8545 --chain.chainId 1'...

Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
Transaction sent: 0x76e785736e8b1c4f8eb0f1342753c3dae770570968d25d12f13eeb8ea5f8379f
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 2
  Transaction confirmed   Block: 14774659   Gas used: 43738 (0.36%)

Received 1e+17 WETH
Transaction sent: 0x4773bc855f919f18964568cd3e34068c9fa6527e78a225030757890a1af49ed0
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 3
  LandLord.constructor confirmed   Block: 14774660   Gas used: 163924 (1.37%)
  LandLord deployed at: 0x6951b5Bd815043E3F842c1b026b0Fa888Cc2DD85

AAVVEE ADDRESS: 0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9!!!

ERC20 ADDRESS: 0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2!!!

Aacount ADDRESS: 0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871!!!

Approving ERC20 token...
Transaction sent: 0xe59e66cc0fe9216757498e4f3f8602e39bca89fa66132e6188eccaeaa1410778
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 4
  Transaction confirmed   Block: 14774661   Gas used: 43952 (0.37%)

  Transaction confirmed   Block: 14774661   Gas used: 43952 (0.37%)

Approved!
Transaction sent: 0x9158e07b307a9c77974bec4e7182ad7aae24e8f18d80b09de60ac22c637dcd55
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 5
  LandLord.transferToAave confirmed   Block: 14774662   Gas used: 24950 (0.21%)

  LandLord.transferToAave confirmed   Block: 14774662   Gas used: 24950 (0.21%)

{'printme': [OrderedDict([('aavePool', '0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9'), ('_amount', 1000000000000000), ('sender', '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871'), ('tokenUsedForPayments', '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2')])]}
Deposited!
Terminating local RPC client...
```